# Maintaining the final state at end of a CSS animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm running an animation on some elements that are set to `opacity: 0;` in the CSS. The animation class is applied onClick, and, using keyframes, it changes the opacity from `0` to `1` (among other things).

Unfortunately, when the animation is over, the elements go back to `opacity: 0` (in both Firefox and Chrome). My natural thinking would be that animated elements maintain the final state, overriding their original properties. Is this not true? And if not, how can I get the element to do so?

The code (prefixed versions not included):

```
@keyframes bubble {
    0%   { transform:scale(0.5); opacity:0.0; }
    50%  { transform:scale(1.2); opacity:0.5; }
    100% { transform:scale(1.0); opacity:1.0; }
}
```

Answer (score 856, accepted):

Try adding `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`. For example, the shorthand would be used like this:

```css
animation: bubble 1.0s forwards;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode

Comment: You can read about the animation-fill-mode property here - http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-animations/#animation-fill-mode-property Hope that helps!

Comment: @Dan the `forwards` value of the `animation-fill-mode` property makes sure element would hold the last keyframe state of animation after animation ends. for example if your animation changes `width` from 0 to 100px, this property makes sure the element remains 100px wide after animation ends.

Comment: don't forget to specify `100% / to` point in `@keyframe` otherwise it wont work.

Comment: I had an issue with this approach: at least in Chrome, even after the animation ended, the renderer was still sucking up graphics resources, making the application less responsive. Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67032976/636561) for a different approach.

Comment: Sometimes I think the people making the CSS API and I are from different planets

Answer (score 95):

If you are using more animation attributes the **shorthand** is:

```
animation: bubble 2s linear 0.5s 1 normal forwards;
```

This gives:

- `bubble` animation name
- `2s` duration
- `linear` timing-function
- `0.5s` delay
- `1` iteration-count (can be '`infinite`')
- `normal` direction
- `forwards` fill-mode (set 'backwards' if you want to have compatibility to use the end position as the final state[this is to support browsers that has animations turned off]{and to answer only the title, and not your specific case})

**Available timing-functions:**

```
ease | ease-in | ease-out | ease-in-out | linear | step-start | step-end
```

**Available directions**

```
normal | reverse | alternate | alternate-reverse
```

Answer (score 40):

**IF NOT USING THE SHORT HAND VERSION:** Make sure the `animation-fill-mode: forwards` is **AFTER** the animation declaration or it will not work...

```
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-name: appear;
animation-duration: 1s;
animation-delay: 1s;
```

vs

```
animation-name: appear;
animation-duration: 1s;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-delay: 1s;
```

Comment: As of 2023 in Chrome 108.0.5359.124 (Official Build) (64-bit) **it seems not to matter** if the `animation-fill-mode` line comes before or after or even in another curly braces block or another stylesheet than the `animation-name` or other properties in you snippets. **And it would be strange if it did matter**, since it would completely contradict other parts of the CSS spec (which define the computation of the final applied rules). Though, I'm not sure if I understood you correctly.

Answer (score 15):

Use 
**animation-fill-mode: forwards;**

```
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

The element will retain the style values that is set by the last keyframe (depends on animation-direction and animation-iteration-count).

Note: The @keyframes rule is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.

**Working example**

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position :relative;
  -webkit-animation: mymove 3ss forwards; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation: bubble 3s forwards;
  /* animation-name: bubble; 
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; */
}

/* Safari */
@-webkit-keyframes bubble  {
  0%   { transform:scale(0.5); opacity:0.0; left:0}
    50%  { transform:scale(1.2); opacity:0.5; left:100px}
    100% { transform:scale(1.0); opacity:1.0; left:200px}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes bubble  {
   0%   { transform:scale(0.5); opacity:0.0; left:0}
    50%  { transform:scale(1.2); opacity:0.5; left:100px}
    100% { transform:scale(1.0); opacity:1.0; left:200px}
}
```

```html
<h1>The keyframes </h1>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I had an issue using `forwards`: at least in Chrome, even after the animation ended, the renderer was still sucking up graphics resources, making the application less responsive.

An approach that does not cause this trouble is by using an `EventListener`.

CSS animations emit events, so you can use the [animationend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event) event to intervene when the animation ends.

**CSS**

```css
.fade_in {
  animation: fadeIn 2s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

**JavaScript**

```javascript
const element = document.getElementById("element-to-be-animated");

element.addEventListener("animationend", () => {
    // Set your final state here. For example:
    element.style["opacity"] = 1;
}, { once: true });
```

The option `once: true` tells the engine to remove the event listener after its execution, leaving your application fresh and clean.

I have created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bazso19h/) to show how it works.