# How to combine many CSS animation nth-of-type selectors into one?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-selectors, css-animations

Given a large set of `<hr>` html elements which at page load should change color one after another. At the moment the animation works but it requires a large amount of repetitive manual labour in CSS for each consequtive newly added `<hr>` element in html. Since the transition intervals is the same for each next `<hr>` line, could this be written in a more elegant and shorter way in CSS?

The goal is to be able to add new hr elements **without the need to change the CSS every time.**

Again: this question is about how to do this (more elegantly) in CSS alone? (without js/sass/scss)

```css
nav hr{
    border-top: 3px solid #BBB;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
 
nav hr:nth-of-type(01){animation: .5s ease 0.0s 1 gogo}
nav hr:nth-of-type(02){animation: .5s ease 0.1s 1 gogo}
nav hr:nth-of-type(03){animation: .5s ease 0.2s 1 gogo}
nav hr:nth-of-type(04){animation: .5s ease 0.3s 1 gogo}
nav hr:nth-of-type(05){animation: .5s ease 0.4s 1 gogo}
nav hr:nth-of-type(06){animation: .5s ease 0.5s 1 gogo}
nav hr:nth-of-type(07){animation: .5s ease 0.6s 1 gogo}
nav hr:nth-of-type(08){animation: .5s ease 0.7s 1 gogo}
nav hr:nth-of-type(09){animation: .5s ease 0.8s 1 gogo}
nav hr:nth-of-type(10){animation: .5s ease 0.9s 1 gogo}
nav hr:nth-of-type(11){animation: .5s ease 1.0s 1 gogo}
nav hr:nth-of-type(12){animation: .5s ease 1.1s 1 gogo}
 /* Boy this takes a lot of time for every new <hr> added in the html */

@keyframes gogo {
    0%   {border-top-color: #DDD}
    100% {border-top-color: #00F}
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
</nav>
```

## [JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/22oqcs1j/)

Comment: Is javascript out of the question? That would be the obvious solution I think...

Comment: You can't do it "elegantly", you just have to combine them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maintaining the final state at end of a CSS3 animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991164/maintaining-the-final-state-at-end-of-a-css3-animation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using less or scss you can generate your css without the manual labour. But it's still far from elegant.

Maybe some CSS genius knows something I don't, but I don't see any way around some minimal JavaScript:

```js
var hrs = document.getElementsByTagName('hr');
for (var c = 0; c < hrs.length; c++) {
  hrs[c].style.animation = ".5s ease " + (c * 0.1) + "s 1 forwards gogo";
}
```

```css
nav hr {
  border-top: 3px solid #BBB;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

@keyframes gogo {
  0% {
    border-top-color: #DDD
  }
  100% {
    border-top-color: #00F
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Mikk3lRo! This question is about how to do this (more elegantly) in pure CSS alone! (without js/sass/scss). Still +1 for your answer: if NO pure CSS method exists, then i will consider your answer.

Comment: I did understand it, and I do understand the desire to *not* use JS for visual styles. I'm also hoping someone can come up with a pure CSS solution, as that would be very useful in many situations... I just doubt it exists enough to suggest this (practical) solution to your (practical) problem ;)

Comment: Thanks mate @Mikk3lRo your comment inspires me to put a bounty on my question which I will (eligable for bounty tomorrow)

Answer (score 1):

To make `hr` stay blue you can use `forwards` as animation-fill-mode, and to dynamically increase delay time for each div you need scss. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8onu6roh/5/)

```
$delay: 0.0s;

@for $i from 1 through  9 {
  hr:nth-child($i) {
    $delay = $delay + 0.1s;
    animation: .5s ease $delay 1 forwards  gogo;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Nenad Vracar! This question is about how to do this (more elegantly) in pure CSS alone! (without js/sass/scss). Still +1 for your answer: if NO pure CSS method exists, then i will consider your answer.