# CSS fade-out and stay so

Tags: html, css, css-animations, fade

Is there a CSS only way to fade-out this text as below and have it stay hidden once the animation completes? It currently fades out, then appears again. I have tried adding `display: none` (as well as `height: 0px`, which isn't really what I want), but the issue remains - it re-appears once the animation completes.

Happy to use some JavaScript to do this (there is a stack overflow answer explaining how to listen out for the end of the animation event), but pure CSS is preferred.

```css
.fade-out {
  animation: fadeOut ease 5s;
  -webkit-animation: fadeOut ease 5s;
  -moz-animation: fadeOut ease 5s;
  -o-animation: fadeOut ease 5s;
  -ms-animation: fadeOut ease 5s;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="fade-out">hello</h1>
```

Comment: Documentation: [animation-fill-mode: forwards](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) Relevant StackOverflow question: [Maintaining the final state at end of a CSS3 animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991164/maintaining-the-final-state-at-end-of-a-css3-animation)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` for that purpose:

```css
.fade-out {
  animation: fadeOut ease 5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="fade-out">hello</h1>
```