# javascript onclick css fade in each time, not just 1st time

Tags: javascript, html

How can I have text fade in on each click and not just the first time using css transition and JavaScript?

Here is what I have so far

```
<style>
#data {
    transition: .7s;
}
</style>

<h1 id="data"></h1>
<a href="#" id="clicker">click 1</a>

document.getElementById('data').style.opacity = 0;
function go(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('data').style.opacity = 1;
    document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = 'test';
}
document.getElementById('clicker').addEventListener('click', go);
```

Comment: Do you mean that more text will fade in on each click, or do you mean the text will automatically fade out so that it is gone before you click again?

Comment: The first click there is no text and then the initial text fades in, when you click again the text should instantly disappear and fade in again.

Answer (score 2):

It can also be done using [Element.animate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate):

```js
const dataElement = document.getElementById('data')
dataElement.style.opacity = 0

function go(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  dataElement.animate({
    opacity: [0, 1]
  }, 700).onfinish = () => dataElement.style.opacity = 1
}
document.getElementById('clicker').addEventListener('click', go)
```

```html
<h1 class="fade-in" id="data">test</h1>
<a href="#" id="clicker">click 1</a>
```

**EDIT:**
In the above snippet `onfinish` event handler was used to maintain the final opacity value since it was being set back to 0 after the animation ends. But [I found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12991203/17175441) that this can also be achieved by setting `fill: 'forwards'` in the keyframe options:

```js
const dataElement = document.getElementById('data')
dataElement.style.opacity = 0

function go(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  dataElement.animate({
    opacity: [0, 1]
  }, {
    duration: 700,
    fill: 'forwards'
  })
}
document.getElementById('clicker').addEventListener('click', go)
```

```html
<h1 class="fade-in" id="data">test</h1>
<a href="#" id="clicker">click 1</a>
```

Also you might want to check [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate#browser_compatibility) before implementing those approaches

And if you want a safer approach you may use css animations:

```js
const data = document.getElementById('data')
data.style.opacity = 0
const clicker = document.getElementById('clicker')
clicker.addEventListener('click', () => {
  data.classList.remove('fade-in')
  data.offsetWidth // required to trigger a reflow and restart the animation
  data.classList.add('fade-in')
})
```

```css
.fade-in {
  animation-name: fadein-animation;
  animation-duration: 700ms;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadein-animation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 id="data">test</h1>
<a href="#" id="clicker">click 1</a>
```

Comment: this is really interesting, I really like this approach, no css needed. Would you explain this part in more detail? .onfinish = () => dataElement.style.opacity = 1

Comment: @drooh The opacity was being set back to 0 after the animation finishes so this just sets it to 1. I also found that `fill: 'forwards'` can be used instead to maintain the final state of the animation. I will update the answer with the new solution.

Comment: very nice, I'm using it like this data.animate({opacity:[0,1]},{duration:400,fill:'forwards'});

Comment: When was data.animate created/released? Meaning, is it browser wide safe for production in 2021?

Comment: @drooh From the [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate#browser_compatibility) it supported in chrome and firefox since 2016 but no support for IE and some older safari versions. Also some features are still experimental so for production I would probably use css animations. I edited the answer and included the add/remove css class approach that does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` might work for you. On click set it invisible immediately and use `setTimeout` to have a delay then show it again.

```js
document.getElementById('data').style.opacity = 0;
document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = 'test';
function go(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('data').style.opacity = 0;
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.getElementById('data').style.opacity = 1;
    }, 1000);
}
document.getElementById('clicker').addEventListener('click', go);
```

```css
#data {
    transition: .7s;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="data"></h1>
<a href="#" id="clicker">click 1</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<h1 id="data" style="opacity:0">&nbsp;</h1>
<button type="button" id="clicker">Fade In</button> 
<script>
var data = document.getElementById('data');
function fadeIn(){
    data.innerHTML = 'Data entered successfully.';
    data.animate({opacity:[0,1]},{duration:400,fill:'forwards'});
}
document.getElementById('clicker').addEventListener('click',fadeIn);
</script>
```

[image: only IE doesn't not support animate]