# Is it possible to use `@apply` in tailwindcss for keyframes?

Tags: css, user-interface, css-animations, tailwind-css

I need to apply the following entering and leaving animation

They are presented using tailwindcss classes

```
      Entering: "transform ease-out duration-300 transition"
        From: "translate-y-2 opacity-0 sm:translate-y-0 sm:translate-x-2"
        To: "translate-y-0 opacity-100 sm:translate-x-0"
      Leaving: "transition ease-in duration-100"
        From: "opacity-100"
        To: "opacity-0"
```

I tried to use the following but doesn't seem to work.

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;


@layer components {
  .alt-pop {
    animation: alt-pop-enter, alt-pop-leave;
  }
  @keyframes alt-pop-enter {
    @apply transform ease-out duration-300 transition;
    from { @apply translate-y-2 opacity-0 sm:translate-y-0 sm:translate-x-2; }
    to   { @apply translate-y-0 opacity-100 sm:translate-x-0; }
  }
  @keyframes alt-pop-leave {
    @apply transition ease-in duration-100;
    from { @apply opacity-100; }
    to   { @apply opacity-0; }
  }
}
```

My suspicions are that:

1. keyframes doesn't work with `@apply`
2. keyframes work exclusively with from and to, so cannot add extra css styles within the keyframe

How do I use css as much as possible to setup this entering and leaving animation instead of JS?

And how do I use tailwindcss classes as much as possible?

And how do I set the delay before switching from entering to leaving?

One approach I can think of is convert all the tailwind classes back to the actual tailwind then write my own keyframes and animation css class.

Is there a better approach than this?

Comment: What are the animations going to be applied to? I've messed around with [tailwinds `theme()` function](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#theme) that could possibly work.

Answer (score 2):

### The recommended approach

The approach recommended in the [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/animation#using-custom-values) inorder to define custom animations you would require to define `@keyframes` and `animation` properties in `tailwind.config.js` file and apply via the `animate-my-animation-name` class.

The above approach requires you to mostly use the conventional CSSinstead of tailwind classes. But coming back to your original requirements,

> How do I use css as much as possible to setup this entering and
> leaving animation instead of JS?
>
> And how do I use tailwindcss classes as much as possible?

Yes, you can achieve this by mostly using tailwind classes using the following approach.

### Using `@apply` in `@keyframes`

First let's try solving your suspicions

> My suspicions are that:
>
> 1. keyframes doesn't work with @apply
> 2. keyframes work exclusively with from and to, so cannot add extra css styles within the keyframe

According to the docs for the [`@apply`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#apply) directive,

> Use @apply to inline any existing utility classes into your own custom
> CSS.

When we are defining a [`@keyframes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) rule, the CSS styling is applied within `from` and `to` blocks in order to define styles for the waypoints within the animation. So your animation style definition would look like this.

```css
@keyframes alt-pop-enter {
  from {
    @apply translate-y-2 opacity-0 sm:translate-y-0 sm:translate-x-2;
  }
  to {
    @apply translate-y-0 opacity-100 sm:translate-x-0;
  }
}
@keyframes alt-pop-leave {
  from {
    @apply opacity-100;
  }
  to {
    @apply opacity-0;
  }
}
```

### Error in applying animation

The following lines in your code is invalid when applying CSS animations.

```
@apply transform ease-out duration-300 transition;
@apply transition ease-in duration-100;
```

You seem to have tried to use `transition` property inside `@keyframes` together. In CSS `animation` and `transition` are two different ways to animate an object. You can read more [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-animation-transition-timing-functions-css/). As mentioned in MDN docs above

> The @keyframes CSS at-rule controls the intermediate steps in a CSS
> animation sequence by defining styles for keyframes (or waypoints)
> along the animation sequence.

Also note that the property `transform` class [isn't required](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide#automatic-transforms-and-filters) in tailwind Version 3 since the transform values such as `rotate`, `scale`, etc are applied via individual styles such as `rotate-1` and `scale-50` instead of adjusting tailwind variables as in [version 2](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/transform)

### Fixing the animation

Now since we are having two separate animations to be defined, we need to use a custom CSS property to extract a separate class. We can make use of [animation shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation#syntax) property. For our purpose, the order of `animation` property values would look like this

```
duration | easing-function | delay | name, duration | easing-function | delay | name
```

Here is how it would look in CSS code

```
.alt-pop {
   animation: 300ms ease-out alt-pop-enter, 100ms ease-in 500ms alt-pop-leave;
}
```

Notice we add an extra `500ms` value to animation for it to delay by 500ms after the animation has started. This includes 300ms for the initial animation to occur and then another 00ms pause before the second animation inititaes. Then you can apply the class to HTML element and use as required

```
<div class="alt-pop">Content</div>
```

Here is a link to the solved animation: https://play.tailwindcss.com/uLgEAAd5Of?file=css

Comment: How is the `transform` and `transition` in Entering and `transition` in Leaving handled?

This is the loom where I explained my follow up question https://www.loom.com/share/6d492ccb2a44423a95d85cf04123c291

Comment: also in your sandbox example in play.tailwindcss, i expected the div to be completely hidden in the end because opacity-0, but it's still visible to me at the end. Am I missing something?

Comment: @KimStacks Let me check out your explanation and get back to you

Comment: https://share.cleanshot.com/MBxKNC6R is having media queries inside keyframes valid CSS? I honestly cannot tell

Comment: For `transform` i accept that tailwindcss v3 no longer supports this and that for `transition` it can be replaced with animation css. I am left wit the questions of why the last animation is supposed to be opacity-0 but it's still visible to me in the sandbox and is it still valid to have media queries inside keyframes in the generated CSS?

Comment: actually i am now less sure that `transition` can be replaced with animation. it seems here https://tailwindcss.com/docs/transition-property transition class in v3 tailwind will assign diff CSS properties altogether that's not handled by animation CSS properties

Comment: since the entering and leaving both have `transition` what I have tried is to add it to the class .alt-pop. Also I have increased the animation delay to 3000ms. see https://share.cleanshot.com/njpWRhjz for my changes. This is what I modified from your sandbox. At the end you notice the flicker. I wonder why. https://play.tailwindcss.com/GCyxPNV2Ir?file=css

Comment: Is the flicker because bg-green-50 has its own background opacity? https://share.cleanshot.com/VpMsfH0s I thought bg-green-50 doesn't have bg-opacity according to the docs? https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-color

Comment: I have tried to solve the flicker using forwards in the animation-fill-mode property https://play.tailwindcss.com/Q82JUO4qTI?file=css This is my change https://share.cleanshot.com/TpGLgjyp and I read about maintaining the end state of the animation from https://stackoverflow.com/a/12991203/80353 Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: I gave you bounty even though you didn;t come back to clean up the answer. Your answer as of 2023-03-21 14:12 UTC is still very useful to me hence the bounty of 200

Answer (score 0):

There are some invalid syntax/conceptions with the provided code:

```
.alt-pop {
  animation: alt-pop-enter, alt-pop-leave;
}
```

This applies both of these named animations at the same time - probably not you'd want. Also note that no duration has been provided so the duration for both these animations is `0s` and thus there would be no visual effect.

```
@keyframes alt-pop-enter {
  @apply transform ease-out duration-300 transition;
  /* … */
}
@keyframes alt-pop-leave {
  @apply transition ease-in duration-100;
  /* … */
}
```

You can't use `@apply` as immediate "child" of `@keyframes`, since this would conceptually output something like:

```
@keyframes alt-pop-enter {
  transform: /* … */;
  transition-timing-function: /* … */;
  /* … */
}
```

And this is invalid CSS.

```
@apply transform ease-out duration-300 transition;
/* … */
@apply transition ease-in duration-100;
```

It feels like you are trying to manipulate the `animation`, but you are using classes that set `transition-*` properties. These properties do not affect `animation`.

---

> How do I use css as much as possible to setup this entering and leaving animation instead of JS?

There will always be some aspect of JavaScript needed, since the CSS needs to be applied on the event when the animation needs to play.

> And how do I use tailwindcss classes as much as possible?

Use your existing solution with the enter/leave classes.

> And how do I set the delay before switching from entering to leaving?

This would be best done in the JavaScript that controls the enter/leaving classes. Otherwise, you could add a `delay-*` class to the `leaving` set of classes.

> One approach I can think of is convert all the tailwind classes back to the actual tailwind then write my own keyframes and animation css class.
> Is there a better approach than this?

Yes, your existing enter/leave classes.

---

#### Edit 1: Reply to @Kim Stacks

> "What about the answer provided by Rifky Niyas at stackoverflow.com/a/75715839/80353? there's also a sandbox example of his solution. It seems that it's possible to do so without any JS"

It might seem working, but if you see keenly, your asked requirement is not met. Further I would refer your own comment to prove my point.

> How is the transform and transition in Entering and transition in Leaving handled?

> also in your sandbox example in play.tailwindcss, i expected the div to be completely hidden in the end because opacity-0, but it's still visible to me at the end. Am I missing something?

```
@keyframes alt-pop-enter {
  from {
    @apply translate-y-2 opacity-0 sm:translate-y-0 sm:translate-x-2;
  }
  to {
    @apply translate-y-0 opacity-100 sm:translate-x-0;
  }
}
```

Adding on you can't use variants in `@keyframes` since it would produce invalid CSS. In this instance, you'd create a separate `@keyframes` for the `sm:` case and then apply that to the `.alt-pop` class. Something like:

```
.alt-pop {
  animation: 300ms ease-out alt-pop-enter, 100ms ease-in 500ms alt-pop-leave;
}

@media screen(sm) {
  .alt-pop {
    animation: 300ms ease-out alt-pop-enter-sm, 100ms ease-in 500ms alt-pop-leave;
  }
}

@keyframes alt-pop-enter {
  from {
    @apply translate-y-2 opacity-0;
  }
  to {
    @apply translate-y-0 opacity-100;
  }
}

@keyframes alt-pop-enter-sm {
  from {
    @apply opacity-0 translate-x-2;
  }
  to {
    @apply opacity-100 translate-x-0;
  }
}
```

#### Edit 2: Reply to @Rifky Niyas

Your @keyframes compile to:

```
@keyframes alt-pop-enter {
  from {
    --tw-translate-y: 0.5rem;
    transform: translate(var(--tw-translate-x), var(--tw-translate-y)) rotate(var(--tw-rotate)) skewX(var(--tw-skew-x)) skewY(var(--tw-skew-y)) scaleX(var(--tw-scale-x)) scaleY(var(--tw-scale-y));
    opacity: 0;
  }

  @media (min-width: 640px) {
    from {
      --tw-translate-y: 0px;
      --tw-translate-x: 0.5rem;
      transform: translate(var(--tw-translate-x), var(--tw-translate-y)) rotate(var(--tw-rotate)) skewX(var(--tw-skew-x)) skewY(var(--tw-skew-y)) scaleX(var(--tw-scale-x)) scaleY(var(--tw-scale-y));
    }
  }

  to {
    --tw-translate-y: 0px;
    transform: translate(var(--tw-translate-x), var(--tw-translate-y)) rotate(var(--tw-rotate)) skewX(var(--tw-skew-x)) skewY(var(--tw-skew-y)) scaleX(var(--tw-scale-x)) scaleY(var(--tw-scale-y));
    opacity: 1;
  }

  @media (min-width: 640px) {
    to {
      --tw-translate-x: 0px;
      transform: translate(var(--tw-translate-x), var(--tw-translate-y)) rotate(var(--tw-rotate)) skewX(var(--tw-skew-x)) skewY(var(--tw-skew-y)) scaleX(var(--tw-scale-x)) scaleY(var(--tw-scale-y));
    }
  }
}
```

*Where the @media rules inside the @keyframes is invalid CSS*

Comment: What about the answer provided by Rifky Niyas at https://stackoverflow.com/a/75715839/80353? there's also a sandbox example of his solution. It seems that it's possible to do so without any JS

Comment: @KimStacks, i have edited my answer for clarity, hope it helps.

Comment: @BouncyBits It doesn't seem to produce invalid CSS as you can see in the components tab in generated CSS for tailwind playground. The responsive variation seem to work as intended. Have I got it wrong?

Comment: @RifkyNiyas, please find the updated post. Let me know if you need further assistance. I'll be pleased to provide more evidence.

Answer (score 0):

`@apply` is a feature of `tailwindcss` that allows you to extract a set of CSS declarations as a class and apply it to an element. You can use it to simplify writing and maintain CSS styles.

`Keyframes`, on the other hand, define the intermediate steps in an animation. They are not applied directly to an element. You can reference them in an animation definition.

So, No, it is not possible to use `@apply` in `tailwindcss` for keyframes.

You can though achieve what you want like below:

```
@keyframes alt-pop-enter {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.enter {
  animation: alt-pop-enter 1s;
}
```