# I can't get my CSS animation of 5 sprite right

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to animate a 5 sprites little hamster:

[image]

I'm new to CSS animations and can't get it right. There are 5 sprites and I'm asking for 5 steps from 0% to 100%

https://codepen.io/Offirmo/pen/ZEPaqaN

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
        #anim01 {
            width: 188px; /* Width of one frame */
            height: 203px; /* Height of one frame */

            background-image: url(black_skinny_hamster--row.png);
            background-position: 0 0;
            animation-timing-function: steps(5);
            animation-duration: 2s;
            animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            animation-name: row;
        }

        @keyframes row {
            from { background-position:   0  0; }
            to   { background-position: 100% 0; }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="anim01"></div>
</body>
```

However the split is all over the place:

[image]

In Firefox animation inspector, It seems that the animation goes 0% 20% 40% 60% 80% and then loop over skipping the 100% step:

[image]

I would expect 0%  25%  50%  75%  100%

I scoured MDN for clues, tried 6 steps, 4 steps. With 4 steps I get the 4 first sprites correct but never see the 5th sprite. I tried changing the fill mode as suggested here [Maintaining the final state at end of a CSS animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991164/maintaining-the-final-state-at-end-of-a-css-animation) but that's not really what we want.

Of course if a cheat and ask for animating from 0% to 125% it works, but that's very confusing.

It should be simple, what am I missing?

Comment: it's not that simple and there is some complex math involved related to how background-position with percentage works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You background is taking `5x100%` of the element width so to make a full turn you need to consider this formula `p = s / (s - 1)` where `s=5` so you get `p = 1.25` which is the 125%

I wrote a detailed answer to explain how to got the above formula: [Using percentage values with background-position on a linear-gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51731106/8620333)

```css
#anim01 {
  width: 188px; /* Width of one frame */
  height: 203px; /* Height of one frame */
  background-image: url(https://www.offirmo.net/x/share/202401-black_skinny_hamster--row.png);
  animation-timing-function: steps(5);
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: row;
}

@keyframes row {
  to {
    background-position: 125% 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="anim01"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. So you're saying that using 125% is the right way to do it? I'll go through a resource I have about animations to confirm before accepting the answer. Thanks again!

Comment: @Offirmo it's not really about animation, it's more about background-position combined with percentage. That's what you need to understand and I linked to another answer that explain the formula I used