Toggle hide/show text on Scroll
Content disappear on scroll like I want but then reappears later down the website, I don't want it to reappear again
Tried  making a on scroll animation and expected for the object to animate on scroll and not appear again on scroll. The animation and everything is working perfectly fine but its just after the animation that the problem occurs
This is the before scroll animation
This is after scroll animation, I don't want the "scroll down" text to appear anymore after scrolling down
Here's the css code for the  scrolldown animation:
.scrolldown{
position: fixed;
font-size: 10px;
font-weight: 600;
left:45px;
writing-mode: vertical-lr;
height: 200px;
bottom:0;
color: rgba(129, 128, 128, 0.5);
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 2px;
z-index: -1;
width: 30px;
line-height: 30px;
animation: scroll-in 1.2s;
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
&::after{
    content:"";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
  
    width: 1px;
    background-color: rgba(62, 51, 49,0.5);
    opacity:0;
    bottom:0px;
    left:15px;
    animation: scroll-in 1.8s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;

    }
}


please post a minimal example to reproduce the error, i.e. html, css and javascript

What does your scroll-in animation code look like? It is likely due to the end state of this animation that causes it to re-appear. This question may answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991164/maintaining-the-final-state-at-end-of-a-css-animation
