# CSS3 animation, picture disappears after moving

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I try to animate a picture with CSS3, it works, but my picture disppear at the end of my animation.

Here you can try (click on a picture on the middle of your screen, you can see another picture who translate on Y axis, try another bouton on the middle for relaunch the animation)
http://jsfiddle.net/58CEh/

Here my CSS3 animation

```
body
{
    background-image:url("Pictures/background.jpg");

    background-image: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
}

#icon
{
        margin-left:35%;
        margin-top:25%;
        position: fixed;

}

#desk
{
    margin-left:35%;
    margin-top: 18%;
    position: fixed;
}
#chat
{
    top: -400px;
    margin-left:50%;
    position: fixed;
}
#outlook
{
    top: -400px;
    margin-left:50%;
    position: fixed;

}
#outlook2
{
    top: -400px;
    margin-left:10%;
    position: fixed;
}


:target
{
        -webkit-animation: soBounceBitch 1.6s linear;

}

@-webkit-keyframes soBounceBitch {

    from { -webkit-transform:translateY( 1200px); }
        46%  { -webkit-transform:translateY( 1110px); }
    48%  { -webkit-transform:translateY( 1020px); }
    50%  { -webkit-transform:translateY( 1000px); }
    52%  { -webkit-transform:translateY( 940px); }
    60% { -webkit-transform:translateY ( 900px ) ; }
    64% { -webkit-transform:translateY ( 880px ) ; }
    70% { -webkit-transform:translateY ( 840px ) ; }
    74% { -webkit-transform:translateY ( 790px ) ; }
    80% { -webkit-transform:translateY ( 760px ) ; }
    100% { -webkit-transform:translateY ( 760px ) ; }
    to   { -webkit-transform:translateY(  700px  ); }
```

As you can see I'm not hide anything...

Comment: Your fiddle does not show the images. Also be sure to add the other browser prefixes for the CSS 3 animations to make it cross-browser.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/how-to-deal-with-vendor-prefixes/

Comment: It was a test, that why I only use webkit, but thank you for the link !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They aren't disappearing, they are just reverting to their original positions after the animation is complete.

To fix this you want to set (in your CSS) the element's position to where you want them to end up.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897724/css3-animate-how-to-have-the-object-not-revert-to-its-initial-position-after-an) thread.